# Do WHERE conditions apply to the result of all joins, or do they need to be applied inside the join?

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Goal**: Grab multiple fields from multiple tables based on a specific date range and field values across the different tables. Specifically trying to grab unique records based on the WHERE clause below.

**Issue/Question**: Total resulting records much larger than expected; the results seem to either be fanning the data. Is the WHERE clause applying across the entire result of the JOIN, or do the JOINs need to be more restrictive in how they're joined together (or is it something else entirely?)

```
select
t.record_id, t.id, t.date,        --t table
loc.location_name, loc.address,   --location table
u.zipcode, u.long, u.lat          --user table

from [primary_table] t
inner join [user_table] u     on t.id = u.id
inner join [link_table] l     on t.link = l.link     --pathway to ploc table
inner join [ploc_table] ploc  on l.id = ploc.id      --access to ploc table
inner join [loc_table] loc    on ploc.location_id = loc.id

where
loc.address like '%specific address%'     --this appears to filter correctly
and t.date between '2016' and '2019'      --this appears to filter correctly

group by
t.record_id, t.id, t.date, loc.location_name, loc.address, u.zipcode, u.long, u.lat
```

I know the total records should be around ~20k records but the results are 1.6m records. The filters are doing what the where condition says however I can't identify what's causing the data to fan.

sample data structure:

[image: sample data structure:]

Comment: Semantically, the WHERE applies to the result set of (ie. after) the joins. (The query engine will apply the filter at an optimal location in the query plan - this does not change the semantics.)

Comment: Formally WHERE is applied after JOIN. Really... variants are possible.

Comment: Anyway, if it "fans out", that is a result of multiplicities *inside* the joins (and ON clauses), not the WHERE after.

Comment: Logically it doesn't matter whether `where` is applied before or after the join, because the result will be the same. Thus, the server chooses to apply it earlier or later, depending on what looks more efficient. This is different to the join conditions (`on`) that are applied *during* the join.

Comment: @user2864740 - is there a best practice method for identifying & fixing these multiplicities? I tried to rebuild the table logic in regular words but don't see what would cause it to fan out.

Comment: You clearly have a 1:many relationship in these joins. This is a data issue (or rather your assumptions about your data) not a query/sql/execution issue. Your sample data would only produce a single result, so it's not helpful in this case.

Comment: How do you know the results should be around 20k? Start from there, and do a join at a time to see why it then joins to many more than you expected

Comment: @JNevill - yes there is certainly a 1:many relationship. I'm uncertain why the data would not filter to a granular level based on restricting one value and how/why it fans based on the JOIN if the the only way to get to the filtered value is through joining two tables.

Comment: @Leonidas199x - there is a historic record of annual totals. I'll try reworking through the step by step joins as you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: There is no "Filtering on a granular level". It does not matter if your database filters first your `t` table and your `loc` separately and then joins or if it joins and then filters. Somewhere in these joins (even after filtering) there is a 1:many relationship causing your result set to balloon. Identify which join it is and consider adding extra predicates to the ON clause or the WHERE clause. Consider a `SELECT *` or adding each column used in your `ON` predicates to your `SELECT` clause to identify where youre relationships are causing records to multiply.

Comment: @JNevill - Understood, thank you for the advice - I appreciate your time assisting me here.